# Deleting item using Ajax request with DELETE , using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to delete a post when clicking the (x) icon using Ajax request

here is my html code relating to this part :
[image: My html]

[image: blog.js]

[image: delete.php]

I copied the JS and php parts from google , I've never written an Ajax request before
so I cannot figure out where I did wrong, please help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: put codes here instead of image

Comment: 1st: the type should be 'DELETE' instead of 'POST'. 2nd: your delete.php is in the wrong folder.

Comment: 3rd: your project seems to be a phyton project. Why php suddenly??

Comment: I don't really know, I googled how to use Ajax to delete and I saw this http://localhost/jquery-delete/index.html so I just copied and pasted some stuff

Comment: Where should it be located ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem with the right location of the php file.

It seems to be located on `/static/delete.php`, but you are calling `/post/delete.php`.

Other than that, you are not (at the moment) using `DELETE`, but `POST`.

Some frameworks use the `POST` as the method, but require some extra field (like `_method` on Laravel) to be present on the form, as some (if not all) HTTP servers do not accept methods other than `GET` or `POST`

Comment: where exactly I am calling /post/delete.php ?

Comment: you're talking about the url in blog.js ? it is supposed to be :  type: "DELETE", url: "/static/delete.php", ?

Comment: is there anything wrong in this line in setting the id :  <i class="fa fa-times delete" aria-hidden="true" id=post.pk></i>

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('#btnDeleteEmployees').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/employees' + empID,
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                success: function (res) {

                },
                error: function (res) {


                }
            });
        });
```